# PHP values not going to the database

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

```
session_start();
include('dbconn.php');
  if(isset($_POST['registerform']) || isset($_POST['loginform'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['registerform']) && $_POST['registerform']){
      //register

      if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])
      && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])
      && isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname'])
      && isset($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['lname'])
      && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        //ean einai gemata me kati ta paidia

        $myName=trim($_POST['username']);
        $myPass= md5(trim($_POST['password']));
        $fName=trim($_POST['fname']);
        $lName=trim($_POST['lname']);
        $eMail=trim($_POST['email']);


        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSTERT INTO users(username,password,fname,lname,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {


            $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$name,$pass,$fname,$lname,$email);

            $name = $myName;
            $pass = $myPass;
            $fname = $fName;
            $lname = $lName;
            $email = $eMail;

            $stmt-> execute();
            $stmt-> close();



        }

      }
    }


      }else{
        echo "no form submited";
      }
```

and this is the db connection

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "phpwebsite";


$mysqli = new mysqli("$host","$username","$password","$db_name");
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

?>
```

I think the problem is the insert statment because everything else seems to be working fine. When i press the signup button no errors appear . The only thing is that the values are not going to the database

Comment: typo miss spell `INSTERT`

Comment: great catch. Also, `!empty()` would suffice if you just want to make sure the variable is not null

Comment: make `INSTERT` TO `INSERT` AND TRY

Comment: ty very much but the problem now is that the execute stmt is not executing :(

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: ty very much but i dont think its needed for that exact project its only for a uni coursework

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is in your SQL query I think its a type **INSTERT**

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSTERT INTO users(username,password,fname,lname,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
```

Try correcting it to

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,fname,lname,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
```

Edit :

For your second issue :

```
try {   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,fname,lname,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")

    $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$name,
                      $pass,$fname,
                      $lname,$email);

     $name = $myName;
     $pass = $myPass;
     $fname = $fName;
     $lname = $lName;
     $email = $eMail;

     $stmt-> execute();
     $stmt-> close();

}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());



  }
```

Comment: ty very much sir . But now the problem is the the stmt var is not getting executed :(

Comment: i am not getting any error thats the problem
  if($stmt-> execute()){
              echo "gg";
            }else{
              echo "nope";
            }

            $stmt-> close();

Comment: try {  
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,fname,lname,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
  
  $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$name,
        $pass,$fname,
        $lname,$email);
        
   $name = $myName;
         $pass = $myPass;
         $fname = $fName;
         $lname = $lName;
         $email = $eMail;

         $stmt-> execute();
         $stmt-> close();
  
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
      }